# onsubmit need to reload page

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a form in a coldfusion page. After hitting save button which is inserting into a table, I need to reload the page with the new values of the table in a select box. Though the page is refreshing after submit, I am not able to see the new inserted value in the drop down. Only after manually refreshing the page I can see it. I have the below code

```
  <script>
        function confirm_insert()
        {
            var ok = confirm("Are you sure you want to save the changes?");
            if (ok)
            {
                document.myform.submit();   
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            } 
        }
    </script>  

<form name="myform" action="bsc_lookup_number_add.cfm" method="post" >
           <td><input type="text" <cfif      isDefined('page.select_Main_Group')>value="#page.select_Main_Group#"</cfif>></td>
           <td><input type="text" <cfif isDefined('page.select_Sub_Group')>value="#page.select_Sub_Group#"</cfif>></td>
          <td><input name="newfirstchars" type="text" value="" maxlength="3"></td>

    <input type="submit" class="button" name="saverecord" id="saverecord"  style="width:100px" value="Save Record" onClick="return confirm_insert();">

            <cfquery name="first3" datasource="mbtran">
            select * from (
       select cast((substr(A.LABORLEVELNAME2, 1, 3)) as varchar2(5 byte)) first_3_pos
        from tkcsowner.VP_LABORACCOUNT a  
         <cfif isDefined('page.select_Sub_Group')>         
        where substr(A.LABORLEVELNAME1, 1, 5) || substr(A.LABORLEVELNAME2, 4, 2) = ('#page.select_Main_Group#' || '#page.select_Sub_Group#')
        </cfif>
        union
        select  A.FIRST_3_CHARS_IN_POSITION first_3_pos
        from kronos_if.FIRST_3_CHARS_IN_POSITION a    
         <cfif isDefined('page.select_Sub_Group')>     
        where A.DEPTID || A.UNION_CD = ('#page.select_Main_Group#' || '#page.select_Sub_Group#') 
        </cfif>
        )                          
        order by first_3_pos        
        </cfquery>

                <cfif isDefined('page.select_Sub_Group')>
                <td align="center">
                <select name="first3" id="first3" required="yes"        onchange="this.form.submit()">
             <option>Select</option>
             <cfloop query="first3">
                 <option value="#first_3_pos#" <cfif             isDefined('form.first3')><cfif form.first3 eq "#first_3_pos#">selected</cfif>       </cfif>>#first_3_pos#</option>
             </cfloop>
            </select></td>      

       </cfif>


         <cfif isdefined ("form.saverecord") and isdefined("form.newfirstchars")>

 <cfquery name="saverec" datasource="mbtran">

               insert INTO kronos_if.FIRST_3_CHARS_IN_POSITION
              (deptid,union_cd, first_3_chars_in_position,effdt)
                      values('#page.select_Main_Group#','#page.select_Sub_Group#','#FORM.newfirstchars#',sysdate)

</cfquery>               


        </cfif>

</form>
```

Please advice. thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to show more of the code. What you have above is just a button in a form with a javascript message. Do you have any of the code that is inserting? How about the the code that displays what you think should have been inserted?

Comment: I have edited the code, the select box with name first3 is not showing the inserted values after the form submit.thanks

Comment: Verify that the record was added

Comment: Yes it was added..to the table

Comment: Try running your insert code before the select code

Comment: This is just an opinion, and how I would usually write something like this.  Look into putting your form with its select query in one template, the insert query in another template with a cflocation to the original form.  Have the form template post to the insert template, which will redirect to the form template.  Nice to keep things separate that way.  It's a pattern called post/redirect/get.  Without it, you stand a pretty good chance of duplicating your inserts when you refresh your page.

Comment: *not able to see the new inserted value* Think about what the code is doing and it makes complete sense. You are running the `insert` __after__ you have already queried the table. So the results cannot possibly include the "new" record, because it did even not exist yet when you ran the `select` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query to INSERT the record is after the query you use to populate the drop down. You need to move this code

```
<cfif isdefined ("form.saverecord") and isdefined("form.newfirstchars")>

<cfquery name="saverec" datasource="mbtran">
    insert INTO kronos_if.FIRST_3_CHARS_IN_POSITION
    (deptid,union_cd, first_3_chars_in_position,effdt)
    values ('#page.select_Main_Group#','#page.select_Sub_Group#','#FORM.newfirstchars#',sysdate)

</cfquery>               


</cfif>
```

above the select queries.

You also want to look into using cfqueryparam - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html

Comment: you also want to look into using `structKeyExists()` rather than `isDefined()`

Comment: Not related to the question, but onsubmit="confirm('really?')" eliminates the need for your javascript function.